# check whether user input is an integer in C

Tags: c

I have read in an earlier discussion that

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int num;

    printf("\nPlease enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

//   Let us check whether the user input is in integer        //

    while ((num = getchar()) != '\n' && num != EOF)
    {
         printf("\n\nError in input\n");
         printf("Please enter valid integer\n");
         scanf("%d",&num);
    } 

}
```

will check whether the input is an integer or not.
The code works.
But I do not understand what

```
while ((num = getchar()) != '\n' && num != EOF)
```

is doing.
Can anyone help?

Comment: The very first essential thing is to check the return value from [`scanf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-scanf-l-wscanf-wscanf-l?view=vs-2019). And there is no need to be fumbling with `getchar`.

Comment: Read a full line. Try to parse the line. If it fails try again.

Comment: You defined `num` as `int`, so it will always be an `int`. Additionally, your `scanf()` only reads integers with `%d`. You need to rethink your code entirely.

Comment: Moreover, `getchar()` only reads characters, so in the happiest (worst?) case you will be able to detect digits, which are always integers. There are no fractional digits.

Comment: The example is very bad. Don't use it. Follow comment #2 - get string from user and verify whether it is integer or not.

Comment: The code originates from the bad K&R book which took pride in writing code in the most obscure way possible. The original code takes advantage of `!=` having higher precedence than `&&` and the fact that the `&&` operator comes with a built-in sequence point that guarantees left-to-right evaluation. And they assume that you _naturally_ understand that getchar() gets an int, not a char. To show such code to newbies and expect them to understand, is like pushing kids into the deep end of the pool so that they may learn to swim.

Comment: (In before some grandpa comes and flames me about how good that book is - "In my days there were no other way to learn swimming! That's how I learnt it and it didn't do me no harm! Sink or Swim is an excellent method!")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d",&num);` will parse the integer present in `stdin` buffer if it is indeed parseable, characters that are not parseable will remain in the buffer.

The trick in this code is to check, after the `scanf`, if the character present in the buffer is a newline (`\n`), if it is, the value was parsed correctly, in that case the loop asking for new input will not be executed, if not, the non parsed character will still be in the buffer, will be read by `getchar` which will verify that indeed it's not `\n`, and the cycle will be executed.

**The problem with this is that if you input something like `"aadd"` the cycle will execute 4 times**, the number of characters that remained in the input buffer.

Though it, more or less works, it's not the best method, as stated in the comments, it's best to read the line from the buffer with something like [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), parse it, for example, with [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and if it fails, ask for new input.

Answer (score 1):

`while ((num = getchar()) != '\n' && num != EOF)`

is just a needlessly obfuscated way of writing:

```
num = getchar();
while((num != '\n') && (num != EOF)) // inner parenthesis not necessary, just for readability
{
  ...
  num = getchar();
}
```